# Is there a way to see the percentage of individual users comments made for git PRs and git Issues

Tags: github, analytics, repo

I would like to know if there's any projects out there that accomplish this task of showing username and the percentage of comments the have made in a repository.

Something like:
Jack097: 43% PR comments 32% Issue comments 36% overall comments
Greg57808: 23% PR comments 12% issue comments 19% overall comments.
Etc
Etc
Etc

Doesn't need to be this format just want the username and percentage of their comments even if only just an overall is possible that would be workable.